# Zend multiple route in one Action

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have Zend application where i redirect page request that coming from `/popular?ref=<type>` where type is either `openings` or `reviews` other than that the request will be redirect to index page. This is new stuff i try instead the usual way which i always do.
So the controller for `popularAction` would look like this:

```
public function popularAction()
    {
        $type = $this->_getParam('ref',1);
        if($type == 'reviews'){

            $this->view->text = "Popular Reviews";

        } elseif($type == 'openings') {
            $this->view->text = "New Openings";

        } else {
            $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index', 'default');
        }

    }
```

i have 1 general view template name `popular.phtml`, now my question is, how can i make use 
partial template so that all model which returned data to controller for specific ref can pass data to partial template then render it to popular.phtml. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [**Zend view partial**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Arif. You need to use Zend view partials.

popularAction:

```
   $this->view->data = $data; // whatever be the data to be displayed on the popular.phtml
   $this->view->type = $type;
```

In popular.phtml:

```
  <?php if ($this->type == 'review'):
    echo $this->partial('review.phtml',array('data' => $this->data)); 
   else:

    echo $this->partial('opening.phtml',array('data' => $this->data)); 

   endif; ?>
```

Note: The path to partials need to be specified in the function relative ti your view/scripts folder - like, "index/view.phtml"